# Validating a JWT from AzureAD using Microsoft.Identity.Web succeeds but then fails in the same call

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, azure-active-directory, jwt, microsoft-identity-web

I have an API that I need to secure with AzureAD so that it can use SSO.

The API has a Swagger UI, so I have (after reading many, many tutorials/explanations/issues):

- Created an App Registration in Azure
- Created a scope for my API
- Added my scope as an API permission
- Changed the "accessTokenAcceptedVersion" to 2 in the manifest
- Set up Swagger to use the OAuth2 flow with appropriate config and values
- Set up the API using Microsoft.Identity.Web and added configuration to allow sign-in to a single tenant

as per: https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-identity-web/wiki/web-apis, setup in the API is as follows:

```
builder.Services.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApiAuthentication(builder.Configuration, subscribeToJwtBearerMiddlewareDiagnosticsEvents: true);
```

appsettings.json:

```
{
   ...
   "AzureAd": {
        "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
        "TenantId": "{guid for tenant ID from Azure portal}",
        "ClientId": "{guid for client ID from Azure portal}",
        "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc",
        "SignedOutCallbackPath ": "/signout-callback-oidc"
    }
}
```

I now have the authorize button on swagger.

When I click the button I get a dialog:

[image: Swagger Auth Dialog]

Enter the client id, select the scope and click authorize. Azure AD sign-in window opens in a new tab, enter creds and submit, then we get redirected back to swagger, and we're authorized:

[image: Authorized]

So far so good.

I then try to call the API itself and it fails with a 401.

Checking the request I can see the JWT token being passed as a Bearer token.

So I stuck some breakpoints in JwtBearerMiddlewareDiagnostics to try and work out what is going wrong.

The following events fire in the following order:

- `OnMessageReceivedAsync`
- `OnTokenValidatedAsync` - with `IsAuthenticated`: true
- `OnChallengeAysnc` - with `IsAuthenticated`: false, and `AuthenticationFailure`: null

As a comparison, if I let the JWT expire, I get:

- `OnMessageReceivedAsync`
- `OnAuthenticationFailedAsync` - with `IsAuthenticated`: false
- `OnChallengeAsync` - with `IsAuthenticated`: false and `AuthenticationFailure`: "some message about the token being expired"

So, what I'm struggling with, is when my JWT is valid, OnTokenValidatedAsync fires and shows a valid UserPrinciple where the Identity shows that the user is validated.. but then almost immediately after that, an auth challenge fires where the UserPrinciple shows that the user is *not* validated... and then since I'm not handling the OnChallengeAsync event, a 401 is returned. My understanding is that OnChallengeAsync is called if there is no valid token (in a JWT flow), yet OnTokenValidatedAsync is called showing that the token was correctly passed and the user is valid?!

Also, when I have a "valid failure" (the token has expired), the context passed to `OnChallengeAsync` clearly shows the reason in the `AuthenticationFailure` property, yet when `OnChallengeAsync` fires for my (as far as I can tell) good token, `AuthenticationFailure` is null...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the issue.

I was missing `app.UseAuthentication();`. Adding that line, fixes the issue and it works as expected :)